# ASP.NET MVC: issue filtering kendoGrid with kendoDatePicker

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendoGrid with 4 columns which two of them are text and date. The kendoGrid is defined this way:

```
<div class="content-grid">

            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<System.Data.DataRow>()
                  .Name("grdTraceLog")
                  .Columns(columns =>
                      {
                          columns.Bound("TraceId").Visible(false);
                          columns.Bound("DateTime").Title("Fecha/Hora Novedad").Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy}");
                          columns.Bound("Type").Title("Tipo");
                          columns.Bound("Message").Title("Mensaje");
                          columns.Bound("Terminal").Title("Terminal");
                    
                      })

                        .Pageable()
                        .Sortable()
                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                                    .Ajax()
                                                    .PageSize(10)
                                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                                    .Model(model =>
                                                        {
                                                            model.Id("TraceId");
                                                            model.Field("TraceId", typeof(int));
                                                            model.Field("DateTime", typeof(DateTime));
                                                            model.Field("Type", typeof(string));
                                                            model.Field("Message", typeof(string));
                                                            model.Field("Terminal", typeof(string));
                                                        })
                                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "TraceLog"))
                )
            )
        </div>
```

For those two colums that I mentioned, I have one textbox for the text and two kendoDatePickers for the date field, which define a range for "greater than" and "less than" on the grid to be filtered. Here is the definition of the filters:

```
<div id="filterPanel">
            <div id="filterInlineBlock" class="content-filters">
        
                <div class="same-line">
                    <span>Terminal:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="same-line" >
                    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.txbTerminal)
                </div>

                <div class="same-line">
                    <span>Fecha Desde:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="same-line" >
                    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                          .Name("dpDateFrom")
                          .Value(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1))
                          .Format("dd-MM-yyyy")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new {@class = "filter-date"})
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "wide-datepicker" })
                          .Enable(true)
                          )
                </div>
                
                <div class="same-line">
                    <span>Fecha Hasta:</span>
                </div>
                <div class="same-line" >
                    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
                          .Name("dpDateTo")
                          .Value(DateTime.Today)
                          .Format("dd-MM-yyyy")
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "filter-date" })
                          .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "wide-datepicker" })
                          .Enable(true)
                          )
                </div>
                <div class="same-line" >
                    <button class="k-button" id="btnFilter">BUSCAR</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see, I created a button called "btnFilter" which executes an script for the filters on the kendoGrid. The javascript is this one:

```
$("#btnFilter").click(function() {
                $filter = new Array();
                $terminal = $("#txbTerminal").val();
                $dpFrom = $("#dpDateFrom").val();
                $dpTo = $("#dpDateTo").val();
                if ($terminal) {
                    $filter.push({ field: "Terminal", operator: "contains", value: $terminal });
                }

                if ($dpFrom) {
                    $filter.push({ field: "DateTime", operator: "gt", value: $dpFrom }); //gt = greater than
                }
                
                if ($dpTo) {
                    $filter.push({ field: "DateTime", operator: "lt", value: $dpTo }); // lt = less than
                }

                var grid = $("#grdTraceLog").data("kendoGrid");
                grid.dataSource.filter($filter);

            });
```

When the button is clicked, the grid stays in infinite loop, as it's shown on the image below. If I comment the datepickers everything works fine, so I suspect that the problem is there, on the formats or something... I really don't know.

[image]

What can I try next?

Comment: Any errors/exceptions on console?

Comment: I posted the solution there... thank's anyway! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it!! It seems that the compiler doesn't make any conversion from "string" to "DateTime" for make a comparison. So you need to convert explicity the javascript variable to a date. That is because I specified the field as "DateTime" in the grid.
Here is the line that you need to change:

```
if ($dpFrom)     {
    $filter.push({ field: "DateTime", operator: "gt", value: new Date($dpFrom) }); //gt = greater than
}

if ($dpTo) {
    $filter.push({ field: "DateTime", operator: "lt", value: new Date($dpTo) }); // lt = less than
}
```